# Finding points with valency $\nu_f(p)>1$ for a map between Riemann surfaces.

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I am trying to do an exercise for a course about Riemann surfaces and for that, I need to find the valency of all points with respect to a function in other words, the branch points with their respective valencies. The book I am using is *A Course in Complex Analysis and Riemann Surfaces* by Wilhelm Schlag, but as far as I know this question does not appear in the book.

Valency is defined as follows:

> Let $f:M\rightarrow N$ be an analytic and nonconstant map between Riemann surfaces. Then the valency of $f$ at a point $p\in M$, denoted by $\nu_f(p)$ is the unique positive integer $n$ with the property that in charts $(U,\phi)$ around $p$ with $\phi(p)=0$ and $(V,\psi)$ around $f(p)$ with $\psi(f(p))=0$ we have  $(\psi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1})(z)=(zh(z)^n)$ where $h(0)\neq 0$.

Now to define $f$. Let $h$ be a polynomial of degree $N\geq 2$ with $N$ distinct complex zeros. Then 
    $$S=\{(z,w)\in\mathbb{C}^2\mid w^2 = h(z)\}$$
    is a smooth affine plane curve.

If $N$ is even, then $S$ can be made into a compact Riemann surface $M$ by adding two points at infinity (this was shown earlier).

Now we can define $f$. Let $f:M\rightarrow N = \mathbb{C}_\infty$ be the projection map $$p\in M \mapsto \begin{cases}z, \text{ if }p=(z,w)\in S,\\
    \infty, \text{ if }p\text{ is one of the points at infinity,}\end{cases}$$ where $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ is the Riemann sphere.

Now I want to find the valencies of $f$ at each point $p\in M$. The only way I see to do this is to find explicit charts and calculated the first derivative of $\psi\circ f\circ\phi^{-1}$, but I do not think this is the way to go. I have seen that for zeros of $h$ the valency is $2$ and for other points $1$. But I have no idea why that is.

Comment: Compute the discriminant of $w^2-h(z)\in \Bbb{C}[z][w]$, at its zeros $z$ is not locally bijective

Comment: What do you mean by the map z precisely? i do not quite follow what you mean by the zeros of the discriminant. Do you mean the zeros of $-4h(z)$?

Comment: Some doubts: I suppose that $h'(0)\neq 0$, otherwise I think $S$ is not a riemann surface, e.g. $w^2-z^2 = (w-z)(w+z) = 0$ is the union of two lines. To study the surface at infinity, I'd consider the locus of $F(z,w,v) = v^{N-2}w^2 - v^{N}h(z/v)$ in the projective space $[z;w;v]$. In the plane $[z,1,v]$ we have $F = v^{N-2}-v^Nh(z/v)$, and $0$ is in the locus for $N>2$, and for $N>3$ I think again that $S$ is not a riemann surface. I see how to add two points at infinity if $N = 2$, but not if $N>2$, I only find the point [0,1,0].

Comment: In any case, for example, for the points where $w\neq 0$, by the implicit function theorem there is a function $g:W\subset\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $g(z)^2 = h(z)$, hence $\phi = (z,g(z))$ and locally $f = z$, so a those points the valency is 1. For the point $(0,0)$, we must assume that $h'(0)\neq 0$ to use a similar method.

Comment: In my previous comments I had an obsession with the origin, which doesn't have to be in $S$. Since the zeroes are distinct, then $h'(z_0)\neq 0$ for every root $z_0$ of $h$. Since $h'(z_0)\neq 0$, by the implicit function theorem around $0$ there is $g$ such that $w^2-h(g(w)) = 0$, and so $\phi = (g(w), w)$ is a local chart, where $g(0) = z_0$ is some root. Locally $f = g$ and $2w - h'(g(w))g'(w) = 0$, so $g'(0) = 0$, and $2-h''(g(w))g'(w)+h'(g(w))g''(w) = 0$, so $g''(0) \neq 0$ and the valency es 2 at the points $(z_0,0)$, where $z_0$ is a root of $h$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand it now, except for the points at infinity. Can we still apply the implicit function theorem there? Also if you want to formulate this as an answer, I can give you the bounty if you want.

Comment: @JarneRenders, I don't understand the points at infinity either, I think the surface is not well defined at infinity for $N>3$, so I'd like to know if you have any additional remark about them. For $N=3$ I only find one point, and possible the valency is $>1$. For those points ($N=2$), you have to choose other chart for $\mathbb{C}_\infty$, e.g. $f(z,v):=F(z,1,v) = 1-v^2h(z/v)$ and the points at infinity are those that satisfy $v=0$, hence the zeroes are $z = \pm1/\sqrt{c_2}$, where $h = c_0+c_1z+c_2z^2$. Use similar methods to find out that the valency is 1.

Comment: I am only looking at the cases when $N$ is even. When $N$ is odd you only need to add a single point to compactify the surface. What do you mean that it is not well defined at infinity?

Comment: Do you think taking a chart in $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ around $\infty$ defined by $z\mapsto 1/z$ would also be a good approach? The only problem I have then is finding a good chart on $M$ around either $\infty_1$ or $\infty_2$.

Comment: In the projective space, the equation is $F(z,w,v) = v^{N-2}w^2-v^Nh(z/v)$, and for $N>3$ (either even or not) I don't see how it could be smooth at $(0,1,0)$, the sole point at infinity. Consider a point $p\in\mathbb{P}^2$, and take the line $l$ joining $[0,1,0]$ and $p$, then the projection maps $p$ to $\pi(p)=l\cap \{w=0\}$. In the chart $(w,v) = [1,w,v]$ (you can see $v$ as $1/z$, as you suggested) you have the equation $w^2-v^2h(1/v)$ for $N=2$. The projection takes $(w,v)$ to $v$, and the roots at infinity are $(\pm\sqrt{c_2},0)$. Here, use the implicit function theorem.

Comment: Perhaps it is well defined at infinity, but it is not immediate. The valency for $N>2$ may be $N-1$. The line at infinity touches the manifold tangentially with order $N-2$, I think.  Any way, good luck with your problem :)